# Netty doesn't detect timeout after channel drop

Tags: java, timeout, netty, heartbeat

Strange Netty behavior: Got a server channel that expects heartbeats and catches timeouts with `IdleStateHandler`. Construction like so:

```
@Override
public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception { 
    final ByteBuf delimiter = Unpooled.buffer(1); 
    long serverTimeout = 1000; 

    // Break input by newlines: 
    delimiter.writeByte('\n'); 
    ch.pipeline().addLast(new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(32768, delimiter)); 

    // Use UTF8 string: 
    ch.pipeline().addLast(new StringEncoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8)); 

    // Timeout
    ch.pipeline().addLast("idleStateHandler", new IdleStateHandler(serverTimeout, 0, 0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)); 

    // Handle commands: 
    ch.pipeline().addLast("myHandler", new DBConnectionHandler()); 
}
```

Everything works fine if the client fails to send heartbeats -- timeout is triggered and handled. However, if I brutally kill the client, equivalent of disconnecting the cable, Netty doesn't trigger the timeout.

Using the Netty's timeout exception (instead of idle event) has the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Netty does recognize the channel drop, it just doesn't trigger a timeout for a dead channel. To detect this call `channelHandlerContext.isRemoved()` for the relevant channel context.

Comment: I think it would be more correct to detect channelInactive(...) here.